What's the most efficient way to structure your landing page content in Strapi?
What's the most efficient way to structure your landing page content in Strapi?
How good is it :

1 collection type as 'home-screen'
Multiple components as 'heroSection', 'aboutSection', 'Footer'...

But with this way we get the api response as (Image attached) where we have to pick first elemnt of data array. I am curious if we ave any better solution than this where we get the required object only?
API response Postman
I tried to configure landing page data into the Strapi which so far works excellent, am just curious about how other developers are doing this.

I feel you are doing right with the way you started.
On my side, I am using graphql so I don't feel I have the "pick first elemnt of data array" thing.
If it can help/reassure you a bit, here how I am doing things:

Single Types: one per page (exception: I consider Header and Footer as "pages".. I only do one call for both of them on loading website)
Collection Types: Each "repetitive" section (such as "Question" on the Faq page, or "Question Category" that can contain several questions of the same category)
Components: custom blocks from micro to macro "level" (a bit of everything inside..)




